# Are Docker containers compatible with any base image or only the original base image?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand Docker.

It does not make sense to me that a container is compatible across any base image.

Is this not the same as saying that any old application will run on any operating system?

What am I failing to understand?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting Docker documentation:

"Docker Engine container comprises just the application and its dependencies. It runs as an isolated process in userspace on the host operating system, sharing the kernel with other containers."
[image: Docker layers]

And to help answer your question, [reference](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/): "**Each container is created from a Docker image**. Docker containers can be run, started, stopped, moved, and deleted. **Each container is an isolated and secure application platform.**"

Saying "a container is compatible across any base image", I'd think of it as "**once a container is layered on top of a base image, it can be encapsulated as a new image and be transported onto any Linux machine that runs Docker.**"